# How to integrate play framework 1.2.3 with Tomcat JDBC connection pool

Tags: java, log4j, playframework, connection-pooling, tomcat7

The Tomcat JDBC connection pool uses Tomcat JULI as part of its logging requirements.

Play uses log4j for its logging. My worry is, will there be any conflict?
Is it good to go with this?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Play within Tomcat and no conflicts here...

Comment: I don't want to use Play within Tomcat container. I am keen using it as a stand-alone version.